# Modifying a JQuery expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#theEmail').keyup(function() {
            if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What do I modify to ensure the expression allows me to enter "_" and "-" in the above script?

Comment: You don't need to call `match` first.  `replace` won't do anything if it doesn't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change both instances of this regular expression

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/
```

to

```
/[^\-_a-zA-Z0-9 ]/
```

Although as far as I can tell, the initial `.match` test is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I agree. I saw after I posted. And your edit works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to right away except... I had to wait 11 minutes and then i left the page and almost forgot.... accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
```

OR

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: I am just having the user enter the information before the @ symbol to prevent email injection through php. but thank you.